# Can't connect dataset to neural network code in google colaboratory

Tags: python

I wanted to write my first neural network, but I can't solve the problem. I uploaded the dataset to my google drive and connected to it in colaboratory, but my training dataset could not find directory content[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uebHe.png)

I tried to download the dataset from the link right in the colab, the code ran, but nothing loaded, although the link was working. I also tried to load the dataset from the computer, but the training dataset still could not find it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.